# How does JSON to case class derivation work in Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, shapeless, circe, argonaut-shapeless

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
json.parseTo[Person]("""{"name": "Bob", "age", 30}""")
```

E.g. as in argonaut-shapeless. How does this work?

I was interested in applying the same principle towards representing the input of a Spark job. E.g. given

```
case class RecordsDatabase(
  people: Dataset[Person]
  accounts: Dataset[Account]
)
```

I was looking to do away with the boilerplate of writing

```
RecordsDatabase(
  spark.table("people").as,
  spark.table("accounts").as
)
```

Comment: It would seem I could just create an instance of `RecordsDatabase` with null params, turn that into a shapeless HList of KeyTags with shapeless's `LabelledGeneric`, and then map over that calling `spark.table()` on each key name, with the correct type available in that scope?
But I don't know how to map over an `HList` that way.